# Can someone show by an example this: "each number moved by p is fixed by s or equivalently each number moved by s is fixed by p"

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Definition: Two permutations p and s are disjoint if each number moved by p is fixed by s or equivalently each number moved by s is fixed by p ?

Can someone show by an example this: "each number moved by p is fixed by s or equivalently each number moved by s is fixed by p"

Answer (score 0):

consider the group $S_4$

The permutation $(12)$ "fixes" $\{3,4\}.$ That is, it does not permute elements in that set.

The permutation $(12)(34)$ is the product disjoint cycles.

Comment: I think you mean to say that $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$ are disjoint permutations.